# JS file not being updated when testing ASP.NET MVC app with VS2008

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008

I have a MVC app developed in VS2008.

When I run the app the changes I made to a JS file
are not being updated.

Is this the browser problem (IE7) or VS2008 dev server problem??

If I use Firefox it is updated?

Malcolm

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. When I make changes to a JS file, my only solution is to to a full refresh (CTRL-F5) to see the JS changes. My guess is that the VS development server is not smart enough to handle static file caching.

I **do not** have this problem with a real IIS7 server on any browser.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the browser.  Here's the trick I use, (and StackOverflow uses).  In your HTML files, put a version number in the query string for your JS files like so:

```
<link href="foo.js?version=somethingthatchanges" />
```

This will cause the browser to go back to the server each time you update your app to get a new JS file.  You can either hard-code an increasing number here in the query string, or you can put in your .NET assembly version info there if you want.

Comment: D'oh.  Sorry.  I forgot to mark my example as "code" and StackOverflow hides tags unless they're in "code" blocks.